# Is there any API to make a video call in Google glass?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

In the latest update to Glass, Google dropped the Hangouts feature. Since the Glass development kit is fairly new does anyone know of any API available to do a video chat using Glass?

Any inputs will be appreciated. At present I am planning to use `SIP` as done in Android. Can the same be applied to Glass?

Answer (score 1):

This is what they said on the Google + page:

> Video calls – We hold ourselves to high standards for the features
>   that we build, and video calls aren’t living up to these standards.
>   Explorers have told us so directly, and fewer than 10% of them use
>   video calls. For this reason, we’ve made the hard decision to remove
>   video calls from Glass until the experience is better. We don’t know
>   when that will be, but in the meantime, keep an eye on MyGlass as more
>   Glassware is built and released – we’re already seeing the developer
>   community work on other video streaming services. We’ve always said
>   that feedback from Explorers shapes Glass, and this is no exception.

I think your SIP approach is the way to go for now.

Comment: thanks Emmanuel. are there any third party API's for Android for video conferencing?